# How can I keep the font format with this code?

Tags: javascript, css

I put up some formatted text on the screen with the following command using inline CSS, but then later I periodically need to change the text with javascript.  How can I keep the text formatting?  I expect the best way to is to eliminate the inline CSS, but I am not sure how, and even then I don't know how I would maintain the formatting when updating the text.

```js
array = ["0", "31.2 &#8451;"]; // Dummy assignment
document.getElementById("Out").innerHTML = array[1];
```

```css
div.Out {
  font: bold 65px Lora;
}
```

```html
Before: <div class="Out">30.1<span style="font-size:44px">&#8451;</span></div>
After: <div id="Out" class="Out">30.1<span style="font-size:44px">&#8451;</span></div>
```

When I do this, the font blows up.

Comment: What exactly does "blows up" mean?

Comment: Also the array element is missing the `;` at the end of the HTML entity.

Comment: The example produces text with two different font sizes.  When the code runs, the font sizes are not kept.

Comment: When you set the `.innerHTML`, it replaces **all** of the contents of the `<div>`. The `<span>` with it's own font style is removed.

Comment: I know.  That is the problem.  How can I keep / re-establish the two fonts when I update the text?

Comment: Include a `<span>` in the replacement HTML. Give it a `class` instead of a `style` and add style rules to your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think the following could work, if I separate the temperature scale into a third array element.  Thank you so much, sodimel!

Edit:  It was a bit of a chore creating a third element, because the main code had to be re-arranged in a number of places to accommodate a third, optional element in the page as a whole, but it is working, now.

```js
let array = ["0", "80.2", "&#8457;"]; // Dummy assignment

  
function changeContent(){
  let out = document.getElementById("out");
  out.innerHTML = array[1];
  let cf = document.getElementById("cf");
  cf.innerHTML = array[2];
  }
```

```css
.out {
  font: bold 65px Lora;
  top: 45px;
  left: 510px;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
}

.customfontsize{
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
<span id="out">30.1</span>
<span class="customfontsize" id="cf">&#8451;</span>
</div>

<button onclick="changeContent()">Change content</button>
```

Comment: I suggest you do not add the css code in the array. Keep that array clean with just the values. Like others said define a class for the floating point value and for the degree 'Fahrenheit' or 'Celsius', separate those classes in the `<style>` section of the page.

Comment: Well, if you mean the temperature scale character, it isn't a CSS code.  If you mean the CSS for the font size, then that is just what I have done.  I created a class for the div as a whole (.out) and a class for the span containing the temperature scale (.customfontsize), both in the style section.  Otherwise, I don't follow, at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of inline css by defining your rules on the `<style>` part of your code, or better; by including it on a css file.

Your array already had a ℃ symbol, I deleted it.

```js
let data = ["0 &#8457", "31.2 &#8457", "-5 &#8451;", "36 &#8451;"];

changeContent();

function changeContent(){
  let content = data[randomNumber(data.length)].split(' ');

  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = content[0];
  document.getElementById("corf").innerHTML = content[1];
}


function randomNumber(number){
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * number));
}
```

```css
.out {
  font: bold 65px Lora;
  top: 45px;
  left: 510px;
  width: 300px;
  color: black;
}

.customfontsize{
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="out" class="out"></span>
  <span id="corf" class="customfontsize"></span>
</div>

<button onclick="changeContent()">Change content</button>
```

---

**Edit:** added a "change content" button :)

**2nd edit:** added a switch function, which will add/remove a class, and then change the innerHTML of the `span` if it has the class or not.

**3rd edit:** split temperature and unit.

Comment: The formatting will not change, the style is applied to any content that is inside the class :)

Comment: OK, but that will not update the temperature scale.  This application can switch between &#8451 and &#8457.

Comment: Well, it's getting closer, but it isn't quite there.  The array data comes in from a TCP connection using a websocket.  It is of the form: ["0", "30.0 &#8451;"] or ["1", "86.0 &#8457;"]  I think I can make it ["1', "30.0", "&#8451;"], but I have to check.  The bottom line is both the magnitude and teh scale re embedded in the array data.

Comment: It would not be impossible to include the scale as a separate array element, but it would make the code more complex.  This might be unavoidable, however.

Comment: You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split) a single string in js. You can use it to separate the temperature form the symbol, and put them in two `span` ?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.  I had already re-worked the code to handle an optional third parameter in general, and then used the third parameter for this case, but thanks, yet again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of separating the numerical value and the degree symbol

```js
array = [19.0, 30.1, 31.2]; // Dummy assignment
var output = document.getElementById("Out");
var degree = "&#8451;"; // celsius symbol

function buttonClick(buttonID){
  var newValue;
  if(buttonID=='b1'){newValue = array[0];}
  if(buttonID=='b2'){newValue = array[1];}
  if(buttonID=='b3'){newValue = array[2];}
  output.innerHTML = "<span class='degreeVal'>"+ newValue +"</span> <span class='degreeType'>"+ degree +"</span>";

}
```

```css
.degreeVal {
  font: bold 65px Lora;
}
.degreeType {
  font: bold 44px Lora;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='b1' value='array value 1' onClick='buttonClick(this.id)'>
<input type='button' id='b2' value='array value 2' onClick='buttonClick(this.id)'>
<input type='button' id='b3' value='array value 3' onClick='buttonClick(this.id)'>
<br><hr><br>
Before:
<div class="degreeVal">30.2
  <span class="degreeType">&#8451;</span>
</div>
After:
<div id="Out" class="degreeVal">0.0
  <span class="degreeType"> </span>
</div>
```